# Correct table structure

Tags: mysql

I need some help with this table structure, because it turned out to be more complex than I expected. I am creating comments and I can't figure out what table structure I should use.

I have multiple tables on which users can post comments to ( like posts, photos etc ), which calls for 1 identifier. Each item has its own id - second identifier. And each comment has its own id - third identifier. The way I see it is to have 3 columns, respectively id, item_id and table, but you guys are telling me that saving tables in tables is not good. I can't think of any other structure. That may be due to the fact that once our brain is stuck with an idea it can't get unstuck, or maybe just because I'm dumb. Anyway I'd really like some help out here, it'd be great if I could get this goin for me.

Comment: please tell me what are the things you want to store?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP comments, texts with maximum length of around 1000 characters. But I need to connect them to the respective table and id from that same table

Comment: @php_nub_qq- are you saying you have multiple tables to store user comments? one for storing comment about posts, one for storing comment about photo etc is that right?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP I'm currently trying to do it in one table with relations, having separate tables would be my very last option, because that will make adding comments to new tables stiff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
comments :

   comment_id     -  primary key
   comment        - actual comment (mandatory)
   user_id        - user who post comments. (mandatory)
   post_id        - post id on which user comments  (optional)
   photo_id       - user photo id on which user commented (optional)
   etc as required.... then status, created_by, create_date, updated_by, updated_by
```

Either post_id or photo_id will be mandatory / their and accordingly you can go

this approach is good one as if you required to add comment for any thing else i.e. videos then just add video_id

Comment: but this way if I have many types of commentable items I will have a lot of lost space due to a lot of empty fields :/

Comment: database memory is an consideration then you can go for different tables for different type of comment. i.e. post_comment, photo_comment ...

Comment: but best is the above approach that i told in my ans